# Delete Checkbox states

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm using these two methods to save the state of the CheckBox, but what I need is that every time the application starts deleting the state of checkbox

```
private boolean getFromSP(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        }
        private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When app starts system creates instance of `Application` class so you can override `onCreate` method of `Application` and clear preferences.

```
public class App extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: A doubt, I'll have to call for each activity that I have.